# Sending a Html form to an email using php on local server(Wamp)

Tags: php, html, wamp

I have an html form which includes input fields.i want it to be sent to a email using Php. I am working on local server (wamp). And on my php.ini file i have this.

```
*[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from ="admin@wampserver.invalid"*
```

Php code

```
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

  //Email information
  $admin_email = "multani92@aol.com";
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];

  //send email
 mail($email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $admin_email);

  //Email response
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }

  //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
  else  {
?>

 <form method="post">
  NAME:* <input name="name" type="text"  required/><br />
  EMAIL:* <input name="name" type="text" required/><br />
  COMMENTS:<br />
  <textarea name="comment" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

I am getting this Error.

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\trying.php on line 12.

I think i need to fix something in the php.ini file but not sure.

Comment: Comment the port part and tell me the result please

Comment: You need to install a mailing-server, this does not come as default with WAMP.

Comment: I commented it,now it refreshes the page and still no email.@arnoldssss. i will try to install a mailing-server to see what happens thanks @Qirel

Comment: Or use `phpMailer`